# Run Promise.coroutine in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I want to run Promise.coroutine(function*() function for as many times as

mmjObject contains.In this case 3.

```
[{ mmjAcceessToken: "x"}, { mmjAcceessToken: "y"},{ mmjAcceessToken: "z"}]
```

How can I do this instead of calling  addCategories function 3 times.

```
function addCategories(req, res) {
    var mmjObject = [
        {
            mmjAcceessToken: "x"
        },
         {
             mmjAcceessToken: "z"
         },
         {
             mmjAcceessToken: "y"
         }
    ];
    Promise.coroutine(function*() {
        var u                 = yield a(k);
        var v                 = yield b(u);
        var y                 = yield c(v); 
        var z                 = yield d(y);
        return z;
    })().then((z) => {
        return res.send({
            "status": 200,
            "result": z
        });
    }, (err) => {
        return res.send({
            "status": 201,
            "error": err
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You can loop through it?

Comment: If i loop through it I get Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.@Evert

Comment: That kind of makes sense, because you should call `send` only once. If you put your `res.send()` calls outside of this function it should work.